# Recaptcha popup is overflowing the users screen, how to reposition?

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

This is a problem which only started today with zero code changes to the pages CSS, so i have a suspicion that Recaptcha changed its code, but i cant see anyone else being affected by this.

When i click on the "I'm not a robot" for a recaptcha thing on my website, the popup that gives the "Select all images with x" response is being positioned on the wrong side of the captcha box and this is causing half of it to be hidden because it goes over the screen on low resolutions.

The other problem i found, is that if you scroll the webpage down, and click on a recaptcha element that requires you to scroll, the popup no longer appears next to the element.

So my question is, can i force a style onto this popup? it has no class or element ID.

Also is anyone else having this problem, or experienced it before?

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Target the entire iframe of popup with css (However the recaptcha does not assign any id or class to the iframe parent div so it will only work if you have only 1 frame in the page)

```
div iframe{
  transform:scale(0.77);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
  transform-origin:0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reCaptcha uses an iframe to load. Google doesn't give much for customization of their module. Try adding the data-size="compact" attribute to the loading div. It is the only other option they offer. Trying to enforce styles on the module gets really messy, really fast.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-sitekey="your_key"></div>
```

There is another option, use the css transform to scale the iframe.
https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/

```
<style>@media screen and (max-height: 575px){
#rc-imageselect, .grecaptcha {
     transform:scale(0.77);
     -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
     transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;}
</style>
```

Comment: unfortunately compact does not seem to change the popup but only the thing with the tick box

Comment: I am battling the same issue. I just found another answer.

Comment: @mattdevio Would you mind adding the answer.